# PostgreSQL 16, pg_dumpall Restore

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, postgresql-16

I'm trying to move a DB from a server running PostgreSQL 9.6 (CentOS) to another running PostgreSQL 16.1 (Ubuntu), I've used `pg_dumpall --clean` (from the 16.1 install) to output the DB's to a file stored on the new server.

How do I restore  this to a new server?

If I initiate a new DB and then use `psql` to restore to it, it complains that the DB doesn't exist. If I don't initiate the DB, it just fails to connect with a message that the `socket doesn't exist`.

Comment: Use `postgres`: `psql -d postgres -f dumpfile ...`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this, because I was using pg_dumpall --clean when I was trying to restore the db it was trying to drop the db first which the caused the error as the db didn't exist. I reran the db dump without --clean and was able to successfully restore the db to the new server.